# Filereader not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, filereader

I'm uploading image files from my PC. Then I use filereader to read the files and preview the uploaded image. In firefox it is working fine. But in chrome, everything works but output of reader.readAsDataURL(); comes empty in chrome.

Here is my code,

```
<body>
   <form name="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       Filename: <INPUT type="file" id="submit">
       <INPUT type="button" id="send" value="Upload">
   </form>
   <div 
       id="div" 
       align="center" 
       style="height: 200px;width: 500px;border-style: ridge;border-color: red">
   </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('send').onclick=function()
    {
        var imag = document.createElement("img");
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("div");
        if(document.all) {
        imag.src = document.getElementById('submit').value;
        }
        else {
        function handlefilereader(evt){
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        imag.src = evt.target.result; 
        }

        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = handlefilereader;
        reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('submit').files[0]);   
        }
        thumbnail.appendChild(imag);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've tested your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/5Qea9/) and it works great in Chrome for me.

Comment: Then why doesn't it work on my PC??? My chrome version is 20.0...!!!

Comment: @Calvin  Have you run that in Chrome on your PC???

Comment: Well I have tried on some other PC's too. But not working. Even in chromium on Ubuntu!

Comment: Are you sure you are testing the fiddle ?

Comment: Runs fine in jsfiddle. But now i installed apache and ran it on it. So, it works now!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open chrome with the flag

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

else open page from your local host

Comment: Why is this not be enabled by default?

Comment: Due to security reasons. by default it is disabled. No need to use this flag when accessing files from host or server.